# Starting xterm windows via cron

Tags: 12.04, server, cron, openbox, xterm

I am using cron on Ubuntu Server 12.04 to schedule the system to automatically reboot at midnight, and on reboot, execute a script that starts a vnc server and opens eight terminal windows and runs a command in each. I am using tightvncserver as my vnc server and xterm as my terminal emulator and openbox as my  desktop environment.  I am storing the cron instructions in the root's crontab, so the script is running as root. The problem is, when I open an xterm session from ssh as root, it says the display is not set. I am using the command:
'xterm -hold -geometry 52x4+0+0 -e /PM1/start.sh'. The vncserver is started earlier on, as root in the same script. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the xauth in the remote server could solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install xauth
```

You might need to restart the server after installing xauth.

Also check your sshd_config file on the server side **X11Forwarding** should be set to **yes**;

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Also while connecting through ssh you should use the -X option to enable Xforwarding. Such as:

```
ssh -X username@X.X.X.X
```

Comment: Xauth is already at its latest version.

Comment: Hmm.. Did you check the sshd_config file for enabling Xforwarding?

sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

you have to set X11Forwarding to yes

Comment: It is set to yes. I'm not looking for ssh over X, the vnc session handles that.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be any